# catching unhandled exceptions in csharp

Tags: c#

I am getting a NullReferenceException in release mode, but not in debug mode.
To try and find the error, I have added an UnhandledException handler, however the exception is not sent to the handler.

There is no gui code, it is console only.

The program exits with the message:
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

To be clear, I don't get this in debug mode at all, I only get it when it is run in release mode from the console, so I can't debug it to find where the problem is.

why does setting the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException not work?

```
static void errhandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + ' ' + e.ToString());
    System.Environment.Exit(1);
}

[System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException +=new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(errhandler);
        try
        {
            new test(args[0], args[1]);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + ' ' + e.ToString());
        }

}
```

Comment: Can you post the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: I am trying to get the stacktrace, once I have the stacktrace, I can fix the problem. I have no I dea where the exception is occurring, and no way of finding out

Comment: That's what the stacktrace is for :-) You should be able to see it once the exception occurs

Comment: I can't catch the exception, and therefore can't get a stacktrace

Comment: You don't have to catch them to see the stacktrace. If it is unhandled, windows will show a dialog and you will be able to see the trace when you open the details

Comment: I don't get a dialog, I just get the following printed on the console:System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Comment: When I run a console application with a undhandled exception, the stacktrace is printed to the console

Comment: Is that in compiled as debug or release?

Comment: I tried both...same result

Comment: I am now getting the  just in time debugger to start, however it also has no stack trace - the pdb files are present.

Answer (score 3):

For handling ALL exceptions we use this:

```
    private static void SetupExceptionHandling()
    {
        // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
        Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;

        // Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through our handler.
        Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

        // Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event.
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += AppDomainUnhandledException;

        //  This AppDomain-wide event provides a mechanism to prevent exception escalation policy (which, by default, terminates the process) from triggering.
        //  Each handler is passed a UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs instance, which may be used to examine the exception and to mark it as observed.
        TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskSchedulerUnobservedTaskException;

        // Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.UnhandledException += DispatcherUnhandledException;
    }
```

I hope, it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. Proof:

```
static void errhandler(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Errhandler called");

    Exception e = (Exception)args.ExceptionObject;
    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace + ' ' + e.ToString());
    System.Environment.Exit(1);
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(errhandler);

    string s = null;
    s.ToString();
}
```

prints "Errhandler called".

Thus, your problem is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Why not put a try catch block in the code?

Like this:

```
    [System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Flags = System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermissionFlag.ControlAppDomain)]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            new test(args[0], args[1]);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e)
        }
    }
```

Or do you need to use a Eventhandler?